# CodeIgniter - Scaling an image and creating an additional thumbnail

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying make it so when the user uploads their profile picture it resizes it to a size of 180x180 to fit in the profile picture box. I then want it to also create a thumbnail version of that image so I can use it for posts etc. This is the code I have right now:

```
function do_upload_profilepicture()
{

    $this->load->model('model_users');
    $userID = $this->model_users->getUserID($this->session->userdata('username'));

    $config['upload_path'] = './img/profilepictures/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|png';
    $config['overwrite'] = TRUE;
    $config['file_name'] = $userID;
    $config['max_size'] = '500';
    $config['max_width']  = '1920';
    $config['max_height']  = '1028';

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);


    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
    {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

        $this->load->view('upload_profilepic_form', $error);
    }
    else
    {
        $upload_data = $this->upload->data();

        $resize['image_library'] = 'gd2';
        $resize['source_image'] = $upload_data['full_path'];
        $resize['maintain_ratio'] = FALSE;
        $resize['width']     = 180;
        $resize['height']   = 180;

        $this->load->library('image_lib', $resize); 
        $this->image_lib->resize();     
        $this->model_users->setProfilePic($userID, $upload_data['orig_name']);

        redirect('upload/create_thumb/' . $upload_data['orig_name']);
    }
}

function create_thumb() {
    $this->load->model('model_users');
    $userID = $this->model_users->getUserID($this->session->userdata('username'));

    $imgname = $this->model_users->parseURL($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 1);

    $source_path = $imgsrc;
    $config_manip = array(
        'image_library' => 'gd2',
        'source_image' => 'img/profilepictures/' . $imgname,
        'new_image' => base_url() . 'img/profilepictures/thumbs/' . $imgname,
        'maintain_ratio' => TRUE,
        'width' => 50,
        'height' => 50
    );
    $this->load->library('image_lib', $config_manip);

    if (!$this->image_lib->resize()) {
        echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();
    }
    // clear //
    $this->image_lib->clear();

        redirect('userprofile/home/' . $userID);
    }

}
```

What happens is it isnt creating the new file, why is this? Is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

one problem which i found in your code you are redirecting user just for creating thumbnail you can do in on step just calling that method in do_upload_profilepicture method and pass image name no need to redirect again and again.

```
function do_upload_profilepicture()
{

    $this->load->model('model_users');
    $userID = $this->model_users->getUserID($this->session->userdata('username'));

    $config['upload_path'] = './img/profilepictures/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|png';
    $config['overwrite'] = TRUE;
    $config['file_name'] = $userID;
    $config['max_size'] = '500';
    $config['max_width']  = '1920';
    $config['max_height']  = '1028';

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);


    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
    {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

        $this->load->view('upload_profilepic_form', $error);
    }
    else
    {
        $upload_data = $this->upload->data();

        $resize['image_library'] = 'gd2';
        $resize['source_image'] = $upload_data['full_path'];
        $resize['maintain_ratio'] = FALSE;
        $resize['width']     = 180;
        $resize['height']   = 180;

        $this->load->library('image_lib', $resize); 
        $this->image_lib->resize();     
        $this->image_lib->clear();
        $this->model_users->setProfilePic($userID, $upload_data['orig_name']);


        $this->create_thumb( $upload_data['orig_name']);

       redirect('userprofile/home/' . $userID);
    }
}

function create_thumb($imgname) {

    $source_path = $imgsrc;
    $config_manip = array(
        'image_library' => 'gd2',
        'source_image' => 'img/profilepictures/' . $imgname,
        'new_image' => 'img/profilepictures/thumbs/' . $imgname,
        'maintain_ratio' => TRUE,
        'width' => 50,
        'height' => 50
    );
    $this->load->library('image_lib', $config_manip);

    if (!$this->image_lib->resize()) {
        echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();
    }
    // clear //
    $this->image_lib->clear();

    }

}
```

you also using base_url in new_image for thumb you need to give file path not http path. i will suggest you to use this library for creating image on fly in codeigniter [codeigniter-advanced-images](https://github.com/jenssegers/codeigniter-advanced-images)